# How to display Multiple values from form1 to form3

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm new to C# and I want to display the Values of my textBox1, textBox2, and textBox3 from form1 to my labels in form 3. But it just show blank spaces. Can someone show me how to do it?

pic:

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the related links?

Comment: Are we to assume you are typing in values in Form1, clicking the "Form 2" button, and expecting Form3 to display them? Or are both forms active at the same time? BTW - name these and it will be easier for you to understand.

Comment: When you want to show data? on form load? or form3 is already open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, on button click in form 1,

```
 private void btnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 frmdisplay = new Form3(txtFirstName.Text.ToString(), txtSecondName.Text.ToString(), txtPay.Text.ToString());
            frmdisplay.Show();
        }
```

and show it in form 3 like this,

```
 public Form3(string Firstname,string Lastname ,string Pay)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblName.Text = "Your name is" + Firstname +" "+ Lastname ;
            lblPayment.Text = "Your payment is" + Pay;

        }
```

Comment: why does he needs a form 2 to appear? pointless. Form2 is just a button

Comment: Because in form 2 we also have an information that we need to display before going to form 3.

Comment: @leimelson06 Then you can do the same way i have passed the information from form1 to form3. same code except you need to pass different arguments

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Depend on your requirement, what information you have in form2 and what do you want to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to load data into Form3 after Form1 presses the "Form 2" button, you need to:
 1. Name your controls
 2. Set your Form3 controls to the same values as those from Form1

Example which uses guesses for your names (since you posted no code):

```
var resultDialog = new Form3();
resultDialog.lblFullName.Text = this.txtFirstName.Text + " " + this.txtLastName.Text;
resultDialog.lblPayment.Text = this.txtPayment.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

in your Form1 class code:

```
private void form2btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form2 = new Form2(FirstName.Text + " " + SecondName.Text, Pay.Text);
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

your Form2 class code:

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string name , string pay)
    {
        Form form3 = new Form3(name, pay);
        form3.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

your Form3 class code:

```
public class Form3 : Form
{   
    public Form3(string name , string pay)
    {
        NameTextBlock.Text = name;
        PayTextBlock.Text = pay;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From3

```
    public void Message(string firstname, string lastname, string pay)
    {
        lblName.Text = "Your name is" + firstname + " " + lastname;
        lblPayment.Text = "Your payment is" + pay;
    }
```

From1

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public delegate void SendMessage(string Firstname, string Lastname,string Pay);
        public event SendMessage OnSendMessage;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 from3 = new Form3();
            OnSendMessage += from3.Message;
            OnSendMessage(Firstname.Text, Lastname.Text, Pay.Text);
            from3.Show(); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add a property in form2 to set the labels' text

```
public string Name
 {
      set{label1.Text=value;}
 }
```

Step 2: In form1's button click event handler add the following code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)          
 {
      Form2 frm=new Form2();
      frm.Name=txt1.text;
      frm.Show();
 }
```

You can add the properties on need basis