# Combobox value from first page show in textbox of second page

Tags: c#

[image]

[image]

I just pass info from this page and save in data base now when I click on submit I want in new page course name is available from page 1
so I can update rest of detail in database
thanks in advance

Comment: so what do u want? What is ur question

Comment: thanks to all for reply .....

Comment: i just make some changes and problem solved private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Text = comboBox2.Text;
    f2.Show();
 }
//Form 2
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  private string text;
  public string Text
  {
    get { return text;}
    set{text= value;}
   }
   public Form2()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
   private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       label1.Text = Text;
    }
}

Comment: in palce of lable1.text = text write textboxname.text = Text;

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the submit`Button_click`

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = cboMyCombo.SelectedValue();
Form2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access to your ComboBox Item by `comboBox.SelectedItem` and then to pass it's value to another form in another class, this couls be helpful:
[How to display Multiple values from form1 to form3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804980/how-to-display-multiple-values-from-form1-to-form3/32805072#32805072)

Answer (score 0):

On the form where you have the ComboBox on the click of Submit Button you can do something like this

Letz say your Page1 is ExtCourse than

```
ExtCourse.CourseName = ComboBoxCourse.GetItemText(this.ComboBoxCourse.SelectedItem);
```

and on ExtCourse.cs

```
public string CourseName { get; set; }
```

than you can assign

```
TextBoxCourseName.Text = CourseName;
```